# java.lang.NullPointerException on @Inject Dao

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao, autowired, inject

I'm trying to Inject a DAO into @Service component, but I get this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   it.cle.project.service.impl.TestEntityServiceImpl.getListTestEntity(TestEntityServiceImpl.java:24).

Fails to call the DAO which is null despite the annotation @Autowired
Below my code:

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">

<!-- INIZIO IMPOSTAZIONI LEGATE ALLE ANNOTATIONS -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="it.cle.project.service.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="it.cle.project.dao.hbn" />
<context:component-scan base-package="it.cle.project.dao.hibernate" />
<!-- FINE IMPOSTAZIONI LEGATE ALLE ANNOTATIONS -->


<!-- INIZIO IMPOSTAZIONI LEGATE AD ALTRI FILE DI CONFIGURAZIONE -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>
</bean>
<!-- FINE IMPOSTAZIONI LEGATE AD ALTRI FILE DI CONFIGURAZIONE -->


<!-- INIZIO IMPOSTAZIONI LEGATE ALLA CONNESSIONE -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl_auto}</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean "
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="it.cle.project.model" 
    p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties" /> 
<!-- FINE IMPOSTAZIONI LEGATE ALLA CONNESSIONE -->
```

App.java

```
package it.cle.project;
import it.cle.project.model.TestEntity;
import it.cle.project.service.impl.TestEntityServiceImpl;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");


    System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
    testEntity.setCampoUno("Campo Uno");
    testEntity.setCampoDue("Campo Due");
    testEntity.setEmail("email@test.it");



    TestEntityServiceImpl testEntityServiceImpl = new TestEntityServiceImpl();

    List<TestEntity> testEntitys = testEntityServiceImpl.getListTestEntity();


     }
}
```

DAO Interface

```
package it.cle.project.dao;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
public interface Dao<T extends Object> {
void create(T t);

T get(Serializable id);

T load(Serializable id);

List<T> getAll();

void update(T t);

void delete(T t);

void deleteById(Serializable id);

void deleteAll();

long count();

boolean exists(Serializable id);
}
```

TestEntityDAO interface

```
package it.cle.project.dao;
import it.cle.project.model.TestEntity;
import java.util.List;
public interface TestEntityDao extends Dao<TestEntity> {
List<TestEntity> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

AbstractHbnDao Abstract class:

```
package it.cle.project.dao.hibernate;
import it.cle.project.dao.Dao;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;
@Service
public abstract class AbstractHbnDao<T extends Object> implements Dao<T> {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Class<T> domainClass;

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Class<T> getDomainClass() {
    if (domainClass == null) {
    ParameterizedType thisType =
    (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.domainClass =
    (Class<T>) thisType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
    return domainClass;
}

private String getDomainClassName() {
    return getDomainClass().getName();
}

public void create(T t) {
    Method method = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(
    getDomainClass(), "setDataCreazione",
    new Class[] { Date.class });
    if (method != null) {
        try {
        method.invoke(t, new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) { /* Ignore */ }
    }
    getSession().save(t);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T get(Serializable id) {
    return (T) getSession().get(getDomainClass(), id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T load(Serializable id) {
    return (T) getSession().load(getDomainClass(), id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> getAll() {
    return getSession()
    .createQuery("from " + getDomainClassName())
    .list();
}

public void update(T t) { getSession().update(t); }

public void delete(T t) { getSession().delete(t); }

public void deleteById(Serializable id) { delete(load(id)); }

public void deleteAll() {   
    getSession()
    .createQuery("delete " + getDomainClassName())
    .executeUpdate();
}

public long count() {
    return (Long) getSession()
    .createQuery("select count(*) from " + getDomainClassName())
    .uniqueResult();
}

public boolean exists(Serializable id) { return (get(id) != null); }
}
```

HbnTestEntityDao class DAO

```
package it.cle.project.dao.hbn;
import it.cle.project.dao.TestEntityDao;
import it.cle.project.dao.hibernate.AbstractHbnDao;
import it.cle.project.model.TestEntity;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public class HbnTestEntityDao extends AbstractHbnDao<TestEntity> implements TestEntityDao {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<TestEntity> findByEmail(String email) {
    return getSession()
    .getNamedQuery("findContactsByEmail")
    .setString("email", "%" + email + "%")
    .list();
}
}
```

TestEntityService interface service

```
package it.cle.project.service;
import it.cle.project.model.TestEntity;
import java.util.List;
public interface TestEntityService {

void createTestEntity(TestEntity testEntity);

List<TestEntity> getListTestEntity();

List<TestEntity> getTestEntityByEmail(String email);

TestEntity getTestEntity(Integer id);

void updateTestEntity(TestEntity testEntity);

void deleteTestEntity(Integer id);
}
```

TestEntityServiceImpl

```
package it.cle.project.service.impl;
import it.cle.project.dao.TestEntityDao;
import it.cle.project.model.TestEntity;
import it.cle.project.service.TestEntityService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
@Service
@Transactional
public class TestEntityServiceImpl implements TestEntityService {

@Autowired
private TestEntityDao testEntityDao;

public void createTestEntity(TestEntity testEntity) {
    testEntityDao.create(testEntity);
}

public List<TestEntity> getListTestEntity() {
    return testEntityDao.getAll();
}

public List<TestEntity> getTestEntityByEmail(String email) {
    return testEntityDao.findByEmail(email);
}

public TestEntity getTestEntity(Integer id) {
    return testEntityDao.get(id);
}

public void updateTestEntity(TestEntity testEntity) {
    testEntityDao.update(testEntity);
}

public void deleteTestEntity(Integer id) {
    testEntityDao.deleteById(id);
}

}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TestServiceImpl` should be spring managed bean and should be fetched from Spring application context (by injection or by explicit asking the context). As the component scanning is at work, your `TestServiceImpl` is already managed with Spring's own  supplied name (com...TestServiceImpl becomes testServiceImpl). You can give it your name like

```
@Service("myTestServiceImpl")
```

The instead of creating the bean yourself you can query this named bean from application context and use it.

Comment: I have changed @Service into  @Service("testServiceImpl")
and my call
TestEntityServiceImpl testEntityServiceImpl = (TestEntityServiceImpl) context.getBean ("testServiceImpl"); 
give this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29 cannot be cast to it.cle.project.service.impl.TestEntityServiceImpl at it.cle.project.App.main(App.java:32)

Comment: By default Spring used JDK dynamic proxy to generate proxy for the target class ( in this case TestServiceImpl) as long as TestServiceImpl implements an interface TestEntityService. So you would cast the lookup to TestEntityService and not TestServiceImpl. By the way it's always good practise to work in terms of interfaces

Answer (score 0):

That's some wall of text. I stopped at:

```
 TestEntityServiceImpl testEntityServiceImpl = new TestEntityServiceImpl();
```

You created an unmanaged bean. Spring has no control over that. Put `TestEntityServiceImpl` into your spring context.

Comment: I configured TestEntityServiceImpl as @Service.
Is wrong?

Comment: That's not wrong. It's just wrong that you created an instance outside of the spring container with `new`.